# Insert a pair key in map

Tags: c++, stl, insert

The way to insert a pair in a map is that:

```
std::map<char,int> mymap;

  // first insert function version (single parameter):
  mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('a',100) );
```

but now I'm trying to insert this in a map:

```
map<pair<int,int>, int> map1; //(pair is the key and int is a value)
```

I tried this:

```
pair<int,int> p;
p.first = 5;
p.second = 20;

map1.insert(pair<int,int>,double> (p,0));
```

So, how I can do it?

Comment: `map1.insert({{5, 20}, 0});`

Comment: The closest to your code is "map1.insert(pair<pair<int,int>,double>> (p,0));"

Comment: what errors do you get? reading them should always be the first step. Please include them in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many possibilities for this. You may choose any of the below which suits you better.

> 1. Using make_pair

```
 map<pair<int,int>, int> m;
 m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(5,20), 0));
```

> 2. Using curly braces

```
 map<pair<int,int>, int> m;
 m.insert({{5,20}, 0});
```

> 3. Declaring a C++ Pair first

```
 pair<int,int> p(5,20);
 map<pair<int,int>, int> m;
 m.insert(make_pair(p, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define and fill `pair`s manually if you want, but it's more common and idiomatic to use `make_pair`, or (since C++17) the deduction guides for `pair`:

```cpp
map1.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(5,20),0));

map1.insert(std::pair{std::pair{5,20},0}); // C++17 or later
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are constructing the key while inserting, you may want to use `emplace` instead, since it will construct the key and value in place and is also better equipped to forward the arguments passed to it without explicit construction. So your first example would be simplified to

```cpp
mymap.emplace('a', 100);
```

while your second example will surely work as

```cpp
map1.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(5, 20), std::forward_as_tuple(0));
```

and from C++17 onwards may also work as

```cpp
map1.emplace(5, 20, 0);
```

See for examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)