# Do C++ need additionnal code when inserting a pair in a map?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, std-pair

Hello great StackOverflow community !
I'm making some C++ and I meet a problem when inserting elements in a `std::map`.

Here are 2 maps, storing an ID-like `unsigned int` as key and another object as value :

```cpp
    std::map<unsigned int, FIFO> _fifos;
    std::map<unsigned int, Kitchen> _kitchens;
```

Both maps are `private` in a class and I insert like this in a `public` method of that class:

```cpp
    FIFO newFIFO(_internalCount);
    Kitchen newKitchen(_args, newFIFO);

    _kitchens.insert(std::make_pair(_internalCount, newKitchen));
    _fifos.insert(std::make_pair(_internalCount, newFIFO));
```

---

Here start the trouble.
Both my editor (VSCode) and compiler (g++) seems to accept the `_fifos.insert()` but not the `_kitchens.insert()`.

VSCode tells :

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert [with _Key=unsigned int, _Tp=Kitchen, _Compare=std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, Kitchen>>]" matches the argument list..."
```

While g++ first display this, after listing a bunch errors inside the depths of the C++ (notably in stl_pair.h):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<unsigned int, Kitchen>::pair(unsigned int&, Kitchen&)’
   66 |     _kitchens.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, Kitchen>(_internalCount, newKitchen));
      |                                                                                 ^
```

I already tried other `std::pair` definitions, like in [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303840/insert-a-pair-key-in-map) but without success.
Considering my poor knowledge of the C++'s depths, is there a type/syntax issue here or anything "missing" with the `std::pair` ?
Thanks in advance for your support !

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the suggestions and the link to the article on code examples/reproduction.
To add a little bit of context, this is a student project, aiming to learn and produce Concurrent Code.
The main idea is to create a pizzeria, where an object `Reception` represent the main process, `Kitchen` objects represent forked processes and `Chefs` tend to be objects managing a single, detached `std::thread` where abstract class `Pizza` will be cooked, for a certain amount of time.

I really don't want to bother you with software design, it's obvious there is some weird or bad choices. To give you a peek, each `FIFO` objects handle a system FIFO pipe, and they globally manage the IPC between the `Reception` and multiples `Kitchens` as the memory here is not shared.
Upon construction, `Reception` have it's own pipe (intended to receive confirmation from any `Kitchens`). This one is currently not implemented and certainly not very useful at the moment

`Reception` have to send orders to `Kitchens`, that's why `Reception` create a pipe and pass it to new `Kitchens` and both FIFO and kitchens are identified by an `unsigned int _internalCount`, incremented for every new Kitchens.
`std::map<unsigned int, Kitchen> _kitchens` will grow to store any new Kitchen created and `std::map<unsigned int, FIFO> _fifo` store each channel for the reception, and use them to send data.
Please note that the `_internalCount` is append to pipes names, which result of something like *`'./pipes/kitchen_1', './pipes/kitchen_2', etc...`*.

I don't know all the best pratices in StackOverflow to simplify and make it clear but below are the Reception, Kitchen and FIFO classes.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class FIFO {
public:
    FIFO() = delete;
    FIFO(int channel);
    FIFO(const FIFO& copy);
    ~FIFO();

public:
    void operator>>(std::string& container);
    void operator<<(const std::string& data);
    void operator<<(const char* data);
    FIFO& operator=(const FIFO& copy);
    void operator()();

public:
    std::string readFromChannel();
    void sendToChannel(const std::string& data);
    void flushChannel();

public:
    std::string getFIFOname() const;

private:
    void createDataChannel(int type);

private:
    std::string _fifoPath;
    std::fstream _fifo;
};

class Kitchen {
public:
    Kitchen() = delete;
    Kitchen(Args args, FIFO newFifo);
    ~Kitchen();

public:
    FIFO getFifo() const;
    bool getStatus() const;

private:
    void goCooking();
    void dispatchOrders();
    bool isFree();

private:
    Stock _stock;
    Time _time;

    int _maxChefs;
    std::vector<Chef> _chefs;

    std::queue<std::string> _orders;
    int _currentAssign;

    bool _status;
    bool _isOpen;

    FIFO _channel;
};

class Reception {
public:
    Reception() = delete;
    Reception(int argc, char** argv);
    ~Reception();

public:
    void openPlazza();
    void closePlazza();

public:
    void createKitchen(std::string order);
    void sendRequest(std::string order, int kitchenNb);
    void receiveConfirmation();
    unsigned int findKitchenAvailable();

private:
    bool _open; /*
OrderManager _checker;  ** Encapsulate other
Args _args;             ** aspects of the project
Shell _shell;           **
Process _process;       */

    FIFO _mainPipe; // Not very useful here
    std::map<unsigned int, FIFO> _fifos;
    std::map<unsigned int, Kitchen> _kitchens;
    unsigned int _internalCount;
};

int main() {}
```

Please let me know if you need something or if you want more details :)

---

**EDIT 2:**
I'm adding here some additionnal errors/note comming from g++ after the first line (display above in the initial question)

```cpp
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)’
  436 |         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:529:14: note:   mismatched types ‘std::tuple<_Tps ...>’ and ‘unsigned int’
  529 |       return __pair_type(std::forward<_T1>(__x), std::forward<_T2>(__y));
```

As always, thanks in advance for your time and your advices !

---

**EDIT 3:**
I starting to link everything in my brain now, thanks from you all.
Things gets tricky there, but I definitely learning from all your suggestions. I'll closely read again the answer of @reinstate-monica and make further research by my side, I have the keys to resolve this and make it better.
Sorry for the lack of clarity, I didn't expected my first question to be as tricky and I wanted it clearer.
My next question will be clearer and I'll try to make minimal reproductible code right from the start, I'll closely look the good pratices of StackOverflow @ted-lyngmo!
Thanks everyone for your support and your time, take care of yourself !

Comment: We probably need to know more about `Kitchen` to see if it has limitations on copying an such...

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: Where's the rest of the error messages? You've removed the parts of the errors that tell us what the problem is :(

Comment: Hello @MooingDuck, there is a lot of errors comming from the underground of C++.
After the message of g++ (in the initial post), there are two errors interesting but I don't clearly understand :
```c++
```

Comment: @Charlie If you make a [mcve] it'll be easier for us to help. Remove everything not necessary to reproduce the problem and include everything necessary to reproduce the problem. The `Args` type seems important - but you haven't included its definition. You also missed a lot of headers. I made it closer to a mcve now. Please fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should be emplacing, not inserting - this avoids copies:

```
_kitchens.emplace(_internalCount, std::move(newKitchen));
_fifos.emplace(_internalCount, std::move(newFIFO));
```

Second of all, `Kitchen` is probably not copyable and not moveable, and therein lies your trouble. Ensure it can be copied or at least moved. If it is, you have to show a minimum example. I can write one but it will work, and a non-working variant would be trivial and not helpful. So show us your work first :)

Third of all: I don't know the design of your FIFO object, but passing its temporary instance to `Kitchen` in a constructor is likely nothing more than a bug. By the time the function where you do all this work exits, `Kitchen` will have a dangling reference. Thus what you **really** want is the following:

```
auto fifo_it = _fifos.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, {_internalCount}, {_internalCount}).first;
if (fifo_it.second)
  // if the new fifo was actually inserted
  _kitchens.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, {_internalCount}, {_args, fifo_it.first->second});
```

This way, the kitchen will have a reference to the fifo that at least has a flying chance at living long enough to be useful.

I'm extremely suspicious of the passing of `_internalCount` to both the map and the object contained in the map. Such duplication of information is a bad design smell, usually.

You should tell us what you're trying to achieve, and a better design may emerge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details ! I'll definitly use `emplace()`.
I'll definitively watch closely to your third point.This is my first steps considering dangling references and (implicit ?) temporary definitions, I think I miss a lot things about objects construction or lifetime.
Passing objects in the heap and allocate them can be a fix to this issue of "reference" or only your way of instanciation can correctly instanciate the object and not leaving it temporary ?

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa what? If you have trouble keeping track of object lifetime while the compiler is doing all the work for you, then how do you imagine it'll be any better if you add manual memory management into the mix?? Don't. Don't do manual heap allocations unless necessary. The `map` already does all this for you. That's what its job is. That's why you use it. Forget about heap when you can store things by value. You'll make things 10x harder for yourself. And you'll be doing manual `new` and `delete` that doesn't belong in modern C++ *anyway*. Heap is best left for containers to deal with.

Comment: Using manual heap allocations with `std::map` is like having a bucket you're supposed to store water in, but insisting that you'll subdivide all the water into little plastic bags tied with string, and put those into the bucket. What's the sense in that? None. `std::map` is a *container*. It's supposed to store stuff. So just store stuff in it and don't worry. It does all the work for you already. And the lifetimes are super clear: if you can access the element in the map (e.g. using `find`), it's there and is alive. Can't be simpler than that. Really can't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I completly rejoin your point of view.
I was doing C for more than a year, so maybe it's a little complicated to see how simple/smart C++ is, as I was used to manage a lot of pointers before.
STL containers are very smart but behind this (curious/foolish) question, I was wondering about my own objects. But there, with your answer, it is more a question of objects' construction/copy when inserting/emplacing in a `std::map`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Kitchen {
public:
    Kitchen() = delete;
    Kitchen(Args args, FIFO newFifo);
    ~Kitchen();
```

Since you defined a destructor, C++ is smart enough to realize the default copy and move constructors and assignments would almost certainly be wrong, so it doesn't generate defaults for you. As a result, it is impossible to make a copy of a `Kitchen`.

```
Kitchen newKitchen(_args, newFIFO);
_kitchens.insert(std::make_pair(_internalCount, newKitchen));
```

insert takes a pair, and tries to *copy* from that into the map. Without a copy constructor, it can't do that. There are two solutions. The obvious one is to make `Kitchen` copiable, but that may be tricky.  The better solution is to not copy kitchen, but have the map create a new `Kitchen` in place as is demonstrated in [Reinstate Monica's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62310654/845092).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I starting to link everything in my brain now.